# ubuntu 12.04 is not waking up after sleep

Tags: gnome

Not able to wake up my system after sleep. It just hangs , its neither taking input from key-board nor from mouse.

Even when I tries to make system sleep by <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>l</kbd>, system hangs. 
In both cases all that i can do is to forcefully shutdown system and reboot.

```
$:uname -a

Linux Ankur-desktop 3.2.0-30-generic-pae #48-Ubuntu SMP Fri Aug 24 17:14:09 UTC 2012 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: I had this problem a while ago with a laptop with a not-so-friendly video card.  Check to see what video card you have and if there's any issues reported with it.  Otherwise it may be a bug you have to report.

Comment: Throw water on it, that usually works to wake up my wife... (obviously a joke)

Answer (score 1):

press on the power button for only 1-2 seconds. Maybe your machine will not return from sleep by a keyboard key press.